# Google Maps v3 - fitBounds not working (pans but not zooms in on polygon points)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm passing in the point array for a polygon to my fitMapToPoints function, this has always worked before (and on other pages), but for some odd reason this now only pans to the object but doesn't zoom into it, even if I remove the map.panTo line.

I'm using google maps v3.11, thanks in advance.

```
function fitMapToPoints(map, points) {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i=0; i< points.length; i++) {
                bounds.extend(points[i]);
             }

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.panToBounds(bounds);

           //trigger the bounds_changed listener as the map WILL not zoom in otherwise
            zoomChangeBoundsListener =
                google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                map.panToBounds(bounds);

                //now remove it as it is no longer required
                setTimeout(function(){
                    google.maps.event.removeListener(zoomChangeBoundsListener)
                }, 2000);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle that shows the problem?  Have you tried removing the first map.fitBounds call, and the second map.panToBounds?

Comment: Shouldn't the "addDomListenerOnce" be "addListenerOnce"?  I suspect you want the map to be a Google Maps API object, not a Dom element (though I'm not sure if that matters).  Also, are you sure 2 seconds is enough time to wait before removing the listener?

Comment: Are you sure you are using v3.11?

Comment: Hi Geo, Have tried removing those two lines and have updated the listener once, but still no joy (haven't got a jsfiddle as yet, will get one set-up) and the google line in the header is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.11&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry

Comment: Also it appears to be setting the zoom (outputting them to console), but the map stays at whatever level its already set

Comment: Hi, I've nw put it into jsFiddle, but seems to work on there so i'll dig through my code line by line if need be as something is not right but heres the fiddle anyway http://jsfiddle.net/mailman1979/HgVcz/9/